# Using a reference voltage in place of GND for ICs

Tags: dac, linear-regulator, voltage-reference

Problem as follows:

I have a reference voltage that must not be loaded and a separate load that must be driven at a minimum of the reference voltage, but must be adjustable from the reference point to 10V.  The reference voltage ranges from 0-6V

Solution as I imagine so far:

Using a linear voltage regulator with the GND tied to the reference voltage, and to the feedback resistors I will connect a DAC output to modulate the linear regulator's output voltage.

Is this solution feasible?

Comment: What is the IC? It really depends on which pins you want to tie to a different voltage.

Comment: Planning on using the MIC5209 GND pin, or the LT3080 SET pin.

Comment: What's the load current, wat's the load, and if you want to add two voltages and buffer them, why aren't you using an opamp?

Comment: There are voltage regulators with a tracking input to follow another voltage.  Without knowing the load it's hard to be more specific, but something like that could work.

Comment: The load is maximum 120 mA at 10v.  I can't give you characteristics over voltage range as I don't yet have hardware.  Thank you for the tip vir, I'll check those out.

Comment: @MooMoo Can you edit your question and draw a diagram with the circuit tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. According to the data sheets, the ground pin current of the MIC5209 can be up to 25 mA, and the LT3080 control pin up to 30 mA.

If I understand your proposal correctly, this doesn't satisfy your requirement to keep the reference voltage free from additional loads.

Answer (score 2):

"*Problem: I have a reference voltage that must not be loaded*"

"*Solution: Using a linear voltage regulator with the GND tied to the reference voltage.*"

The linear regulator itself has an operating current which it will flow from its Vin and out through its GND.

So your reference voltage will actually be loaded by the regulator, which will pass a small negative current into it. The current value depends on the regulator.

So, from the little information you've given and your own rules:

- no, it's not feasible.